# Pass Array from MVC Controller to Javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

is it possible to read the contents of an array that is passed from an MVC Controller to JavaScript?

This is a method in my controller that returns an array. (tried with a list before but didn't succeed)

```
public string[] GetAllEvents() 
{
    string[] array = new string[2];
    array[0] = "a";
    array[1] = "b";

    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("a");
    lst.Add("b");
    return array;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript function from which I'm calling the Controller method.

```
function GetAllEvents() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Service/GetAllEvents",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.toString() + "  " + result[0]);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
};
```

The result is a System.String[] and the result[0] is giving me 'S' as a result.

Comment: The result you see is probably actually the string "System.String[]", and `result[0]` is the character at index 0 in that string, hence the "S". Follow [SLaks' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10213690/74757) and you should see expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC actions should return `ActionResult`s.

You can then `return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` and it will work.